# Text vertical alignment in Enscript

Tags: enscript

Is there any option for vertical text alignment within a line in Enscript?

I have to align the text in the vertical middle of the background.
[image: bggray]

The text script:

```
push (@parts_section_array, sprintf(border("#")."%4s".'~bggray{0.85}'." Part Number %9s  Description %16s Qty. ". '~font{DejaVuSansMono-Bold10}' ."Unit Price  Ext. Price %4s Cost".'~font{default}~bggray{1.0}'." ".border("|")."\n",
                                    "", "", "", ""));
```

Or text is:

```
~bggray{0.85} Part Number       Description      Qty. ~font{DejaVuSansMono-Bold10} Unit Price  Ext. Price  Cost ~font{default}~bggray{1.0}
```

Enscript code:

```
 enscript -q \
    -f DejaVuSansMono@10 \
    -e~ \
    --no-header \
    -s 4.3 \
    --margins=10:2:14:10 \
    -L 73 "${pi}" \
    -o - \
| ps2pdf - "$BOOK_DIR"/"${filename}.pdf"
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider using a typesetting system like [Tex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX)/[LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) which handles handles [tables and backgrounds](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/tables#Colouring_a_table_.28cells.2C_rows.2C_columns_and_lines.29) very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find no other way, you can always edit the PostScript that is generated. My version of `enscript` puts at the start of the output the definition of the `bgs` function that is called to draw the background:

```
/bgs {  % x y height blskip gray str -> -  show string with bg color
  /str exch def
  /gray exch def
  /blskip exch def
  /height exch def
  /y exch def
  /x exch def
  gsave
    x y blskip sub str stringwidth pop height Box
    gray setgray
    fill
  grestore
  x y M str s
} def
```

You need to change the line `x y ... Box` in order to raise the y co-ordinate of the box, for example by `height*0.2` so that it is:

```
x y  height .2 mul add  blskip sub str stringwidth pop height Box
```

Do this by adding a `sed` script in the pipe before the `ps2pdf`:

```
enscript ... |
sed '/^\/bgs /,/^}/{
       /x y blskip/s//x   y height .2 mul add   blskip/
    }' |
ps2pdf ...
```

Your `enscript` might generate a slightly different definition, so do compare them first.