# Add border arond text in pdf

Tags: enscript

I have large database in text format.I convert them in particular format using awk. While using awk i have added escape sequence ^ for formatting in enscript like bgcolor,font,color etc. Then i convert same in pdf with ps2pdf command. In awk when i use printf "|%s|",$1 it is printing vertical line but breaked. I want different borders/boxes around various textfield. Whether it is possible to do with enscript OR ps2pdf OR pdftk ?

Comment: Possible commands may be pdf,pdftk,ps2pdf

Comment: In question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/539818/343138 it was horizontal line. It is possible to change it vertical ?